# Distorted graphics on start up

Tags: boot, 12.10, graphics, multiple-monitors, display

So I am using dual monitors and every time I boot up my machine after entering my password to login, both screens show distorted graphics which eventually go away.  I am on `Ubuntu 12.10` the OS type is `64 bit` and my graphics driver is `Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV620`.  Is there any way to prevent the distorted graphics from showing up at all? The distorted graphics seem to go away after about a minute from logging in to my user account.

**Update**

This continues to be an issue in Ubuntu 13.10.  Is this avoidable?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem in my laptop. but am not using a dual monitor

Comment: Could you be more specific about the distortion? Is it blurry, the wrong resolution etc...? I have a problem where my second, smaller monitor is duplicated on my larger monitor along with that monitor's view. Is it something like that?

Comment: Have you tried using the proprietary `fglrx` driver?

Comment: @toobsco42 are you using any grub boot options such as `radeon.agpmode=-1` ?

Comment: @fossfreedom I checked my /boot/grub/grub.cfg config file and I don't see any mention of radeon there.

Comment: I know this sounds a bit out there but I have seen similar distortion issues caused by incompatible or faulty Ram. I know it doesn't sound very likely but if you have more than 1 Ram stick it might be worth swapping them out. Do you get the same issue with just one monitor attached? @grimpitch the RV620 is quite an old card now (in AMD's eyes anyway) and I'm sure would require the legacy driver.

Comment: I have 3.7 GiB of Memory.  I have not seen the same issue with just one monitor.

Comment: Readings [`BinaryDriverHowto/ATI`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) [`manpages/quantal/man4/radeon.4.html`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man4/radeon.4.html)

Comment: Did you triy the drivers in https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa? I had a similar problem with an AMD A6 cpu+gpu, with dual screen too, and it is solved now.

Comment: @ttoine I added the ppa `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`, and ran `sudo apt-get update` and restarted my machine but it has not resolved the issue.

Comment: @toobsco42 run sudo apt-get upgrade, too.

Comment: Have you tried re installing you graphics cards?

Comment: I no longer have this set up to try to reinstall the graphics card unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

your monitor doesn`t suport grubs default resolution

using your favourite editor in sudo open /etc/default/grub
For example `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

uncomment line `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`
set it to your monitor resolution

`GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600` is a sufficient and definitely supported by your display

update grub with new setings
`sudo update-grub`

and vote for the post, as I don't have enough points to vote yet

Comment: I just tried this, and it didn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for my old white iMac (24 inch display):

uncomment line "GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480" and set to 1680x1050

(this should be a comment to Thomas' answer)
17. January 2020